# Dash not rendering fonts for icon descriptions

Tags: fonts, unity-dash

This is the problem that I am having.

Note: fonts render fine on everything else. Web, typing, etc.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5UDHD6d.jpg]

Comment: run `reset --compiz` in dash

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type  `gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.interface | grep --ignore-case font`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question.